# building chart using mplfinance python

Tags: python, charts, mplfinance

I am not sure which library going to be best to create something like this
[image]

I found this mplfinance library and it seem what i need but im not sure if i would be available to customize the way i want it. Before i spend hours studying this library, i just want to make sure that i can do. If someone can give me example that would help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like that chart with mplfinance.  I *do* recommend that you set aside ***one*** full hour of your time to go through [**the documentation**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#contents-and-tutorials).  In particular, I recommend you focus, in this order, on the following:

1. **[Basic Usage](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance#usage)**
2. **[Adding Your Own Technical Studies to Plots](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb)**
3. **[Customizing the Appearance of Plots](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/markdown/customization_and_styles.md)**

The third item above has two parts.  The [**styles tutorial**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/styles.ipynb) will show you how you can get the colors you want, where you want them.  And the [individual plot customizations tutorial](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/plot_customizations.ipynb) has a section that mentions `fill_between` which you can use to accomplish the two-color plot face that you have drawn above.

If you have additional questions you can post them here (or under the [issues](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues) section of the mplfinance repository).

full disclosure: I am the maintainer of the mplfinance package.